# Bridge Two connections and dongle

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have this setup:

1. I have a raspberry pi , that is acting as a 'server' (Call it A)
2. I have a windows laptop , thats acting as client 1   (Call it B)
3. I have a mobile phone thats acting as client 2       (Call it C)

   A runs Debian

   B runs Windows 7

   C runs android

A is connected to B using an ethernet cable. C is connected to B using WIFI (ad-hoc network) .

B has a USB dongle that is providing an internet connection.

A has a website hosted, that needs to be accessible by B . Also , C needs to send an http request to A . both , A AND C are using things that require an Internet Access. For this I have a dongle thats connected to B .

I tried to bridge LAN and WLAN , then share my Dongle to that bridge, but it did not work.

How do I do all this without a physical router ?

Comment: Your post seems incomplete.

Comment: very sorry, I had lost connectivity just before posting. Didnt know it came out like this. I have edited my question, kindly take a look

Comment: What operating systems are involved here?

Comment: please see question now, added the info